# Zend Framework/Existing Project

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to use Zend Framework in an existing project. I already have an autoload function and I also don't want to use MVC, just some components from Zend.

How does it work to include a component (for instance the Mail component) in to an exisitng project?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, all Zend components declare the classes they need with `require_once` without using autoload.

So I think that you can try to include Zend library like this:

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(
    implode(
        PATH_SEPARATOR,
        array(
            realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
            get_include_path()
        )
    )
);
```

(Of course, you must change `realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'` to match your project)

And then call your component like this:

```
require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
```

Hope it will help you
:)

Answer (score 0):

At this point you probably should use Zend Framework 2 instead of Zend Framework 1. In that case, you can load individual components from ZF2 using Composer. Composer includes its own really good autoloader, which you can train for your own site, but you can also ignore and plumb into your current autoloader.

The Mail package, for instance, can be included using (from the command line)

```
> composer require zendframework/zend-mail
```

Then (if you do use the Composer autoloader), you can just start using `Zend\Mail` in your app.

The reason you should SERIOUSLY consider using Composer's autoloader is that `Zend` components rely on other `Zend` components and manually managing those are a pain in the a**.